# I need to change the colour of some cells in Full calendar, not the event, but the whole cell

Tags: django

I want to change the colour of the whole cells in Full Calendar, not the event but the whole cells, like the background of the current day.

I don't know how to start

```
    `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
            contentHeight: 'auto',
            timeZone: 'local',
            eventOrder: 'variable',

            stickyHeaderDates:true,
            events:

                [

                    {% for es in eventos  %}
                        {

                            variable: {{ es.esTemprano }},
                            title: ' {{ es.icono }}  {{ es.apellido }}   {{ es.personas }}',
                            start: '{{ es.dia |date:"Y-m-d"}}',
                            end: '{{ es.dia |date:"Y-m-d"}}',
                            url: '../evento/aviso/{{es.id}}',
                            color: 'black',
                            textColor:{% if es.llegar < '14:00' and es.llegar > '06:00' %}
                                '#0F8706'
                            {% else %}
                                'black'
                            {% endif %},
                            backgroundColor: '#FCF7F3', },
                    {% endfor %}
                ],



        });
                calendar.render();
              calendar.setOption('locale', 'es');
```

})
;
`